# JMeter counter report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test plan with 28 controllers. each controller is a complete scenario of how user will surf the site and is in an individual thread, so obviously each scenario takes different time to complete. Some of them would take only 2-3 seconds for each iteration per user while few of them take up to 5 minutes. 
I have put separate counters for each controller to count number of iterations of each thread/scenario and I want to run the load test for an hour. Now the question is, how can I see counter results after the test finishes? do I need some scripting or what?

Answer (score 1):

It was easy.
I just defined a unique reference name for each individual counter and then added a Beanshell PostProcessor at the Thread's end.
Counter start was set as 1 with Increment of 1 (Duh!)

In the Beanshell PostProcessor, set the Parameters box as ${your_counter_reference}
and an easy script to see the number in the console:
System.out.println("counter x:"+ ${your_counter_reference})

When you stop the test, look for biggest number of each thread in the console.